# Switch back to New Experience UI

Tags: document-library, library, sharepoint-library, libraries

I have selected the option to return to the Classic UI for document libraries via the option that was available when viewing a document library.  Now I want to switch back to the New Experience UI, how do I do that?

Comment: I figured out the answer, see http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/191244/59089

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to my question here http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_manage/how-to-switch-between-classic-and-new-library/b25035ec-21d0-4740-b7c7-1cf9ba3311bb.

The gist of this answer is that you must clear the browser cookie that indicates to use the new experience UI.  The article states to clear all cookies, but I found I only needed to clear the cookies related to my SharePoint site.  I was not able to figure out which cookie specifically needs to be cleared.

Answer (score 4):

I also wondered further about the session cookie making the classic user experience and it was cookie named "splnu" with value 0. By removing it and pressing refresh button it switched back to setting by admin that was the new user experience.

For convenience it is good to use a kind of cookie manager extension in your browser - I used the cookie inspector for the google chrome (and available as tab) in the chrome developer tools and it was really a piece of cake :)

Comment: Excellent! This cookie tip fixed my issue, I could not go back to the Modern UI experience because of the site layout (Oslo). since the link to return to modern UI is under the quick launch, it was not possible to undo the classic view mode.

Answer (score 3):

The name of the cookie is "spInu" with a value of 0. Deleting that one will restore the modern UI without having to clear all cookies.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the cookie directly without needing to clear them. Paste this into your URL bar while you're on the page:

```
javascript:document.cookie = "splnu = 1; path=/"
```

Then reload the page.

Comment: Thanks a ton, @john-fouhy! I have Developer tools locked by policy and this saved me several hours!)

Answer (score 2):

- In your document library, choose Settings icon and then Library settings.

[image]

- Click Advanced settings and then scroll down to List experience.
- Choose New experience.

[image]

For more details check [Switch the default experience for lists or document libraries from new or classic](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-the-default-experience-for-lists-or-document-libraries-from-new-or-classic-66dac24b-4177-4775-bf50-3d267318caa9)

Comment: New experience has been released for library only. Am I right?

Comment: Dear @AtishDipongkor  it's also for list , should you check the attached link where he mentions list or library but really I saw it for library only :) https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-the-default-experience-for-lists-or-document-libraries-from-new-or-classic-66dac24b-4177-4775-bf50-3d267318caa9

Comment: I have checked the link. In my SharePoint Online site I did not see all new experiences. I can see SharePoint Home and Library experience only.

Comment: You are right my bro I also checked it and checked this article https://blogs.office.com/2016/06/07/modern-document-libraries-in-sharepoint/  any way the questioner need it for library :) thanks for your precious time and valuable info ,

Comment: New experience for lists is in the process of rolling out to first release tenants

Comment: @M.Qassas that is how a library admin changes the default UI view for the list, but in my case a user has selected the option that SharePoint offers to users to view using the new experience UI.

Answer (score 0):

it is in the library settings under ADVANCED SETTINGS.

Look up for Library - library settings

£rd from top in the first column